# why does the node.js file stop working when I add a hostname to the file?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm running an apache and ubuntu server on aws.

Both the below files run but when I access the server only the top one returns Helloworld. Why is that?

```
var http = require('http');

var port = 3000;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});

server.listen(port);
```

The bottom file runs but doesn't when I hit the server I get an error. I tried replacing hostname with the ip of the server, I also tried making the host name 127.0.0.1 that didn't work either. The error I get is

```
"This site can't be reached,  <ip> refused to connect, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
```

is the ip of the server.

```
var http = require('http');

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});

server.listen(port, hostname);
```

Cheers

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by including the `hostname` argument?  You can just leave it out and then your server will respond to any incoming request to this server on the specified port.  Obviously, if you're using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, then only connections from on the same box can possibly match that.

Comment: I got it working by removing hostname thanks. The reason I had it was because I was following a tutorial online and the guy was working from his local machine. Initially I was leaving out the hostname but I ran into errors so I tried both adding/removing it. I guess I was making mistakes when I removed it because it still didn't want to work. The reason I added it was because I read somewhere else on stackOverflow that I should add it. I obviously misunderstood. Thanks for your comment it was a big help mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're listening on localhost, you have to make the request from the same machine/server and not from the outside.

Comment: How may I make a request from the same machine. I'm connecting to aws through putty. If I open another window of putty and type                      "curl <ip to server>" It doesn't work. If I remove the localhost parameter it would work though.

Comment: You probably have to use `localhost` when making the request locally on the same system since I don't think Amazon assigns IPs directly to interfaces on instances?